# is it possible to get definitive/absolute sized types in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c

I've glossed over some documentation and it seems like the spec only requires 'int' or 'long' or whatever to be able to hold "at least some range of values" (often corresponding to the max range afforded by n bytes).

Anyways, is there a reasonable way to ask for an integer of exactly n bits/bytes? I don't even need a way to specify arbitrary length or anything weird, I'd just want a type with definitively 2 bytes, or definitively 4 bytes. like "int32" or something.

Currently, the way I'm dealing with this is by having a char array of n length, then casting it to an int * and dereferencing.

(My reasoning for wanting this has to do with reading/writing to files directly from structs- and I acknowledge that with this I'll have to worry about struct packing and endianness and stuff with that, but that's another issue...)

Also, "compatibility" with like super limited embedded systems is not a particular concern.

Thanks!

Comment: `int32` is only 4 bytes if a byte has 8 bits. You can find integer types defined in terms of bits in `<cstdint>`

Comment: Are you programming in C or C++?  The answer to your question is language specific.

Comment: technically I'm using C right now, but glad to have been pointed in the right direction for both (<stdint.h> vs <cstdint>)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The c++11 standard defines integer types of definite size, provided they are available on the target architecture.

```
#include <cstdint>
std::int8_t  c; //  8-bit unsigned integer
std::int16_t s; // 16-bit unsigned integer
std::int32_t i; // 32-bit unsigned integer
std::int64_t l; // 64-bit unsigned integer
```

and the corresponding unsigned types with

```
std::uint8_t  uc; //  8-bit unsigned integer
std::uint16_t us; // 16-bit unsigned integer
std::uint32_t ui; // 32-bit unsigned integer
std::uint64_t ul; // 64-bit unsigned integer
```

---

As noted in the comments, these types are also available in C from the `stdint.h` header without the `std::` namespace prefix:

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint32_t ui;
```

In addition to the types of definite size, these header files also define types

- that are at least n bits wide but may be larger, e.g. `int_least16_t` with at least 16 bits
- that provide the fastest implementation of integers with at least n bits but may be larger, e.g. `std::int_fast32_t` with at least 32 bits.

Comment: Just to be explicit, there's no guarantee that an `int16_t` is the same type as a `short` or an `int32_t` is the same type as an `int`, as the comments above might suggest.

Comment: They should also be in the `std` namespace.

Comment: Since the OP stated C language also, the types are available in C as well, without the `std::` prefix.

Comment: To be even more explicit, there is no guarantee that any of the types listed in this answer exist for a given implementation. These types are all optional in both C11 and C++11.

Answer (score 3):

The typed declared in `<cstdint>`, such as `int32_t` will either be exactly that number of bits [32 in this example], or not exist if the architecture doesn't support that size values. There are also types `int_fast32_t` which is guaranteed to hold a 32-bit value, but could be larger, and `int_fast32_t` which has a similar guarantee.

Comment: Thanks, fixed (and yes, it was a "couldn't remember which way around it is")

Answer (score 2):

The current c++ standard provides [Fixed width integer types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) like `std::int16_t` `std::uint16_t`, where `16` means the type size in bits.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the types from `<stdint.h>`, but you cannot be sure that there is exactly the type you want.

If your architecture does have exact 32 bit types, which is highly likely, then you can use `int16_t`, `uint16_t`, `int32_t` and `uint32_t`, if not, the types `int_fast32_t` and `uint_fast32_t` as well as `int_least32_t` and `uint_least32_t` , etc. are always available.